# I can't see any folder in my IntellIJ project, only the files

Tags: intellij-idea, directory, project

I can't really see any folder, just files at the project root:
[image: Project preview without folders.]

(This actually has happened before with many IDEA based IDEs)

I've tried removing the `.idea/modules` folder and `.idea/modules.xml` file, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it by following these steps:

1. Close the project, not the app (File > Close Project).
   [image: Close Project]
2. Remove the project from the recent projects list
   [image: Remove from Recent Projects...]
3. Close the app.
4. Open the project root folder in terminal (or your file manager).
5. Remove the `.idea` folder (backup any files you need, but it's usually not needed)
6. Open the app.
7. Open the project again.

Now this error should be fixed. If it doesn't work you can repeat everything above, but before step 7 (opening the project again) use File > Invalidate Caches > (Select Everything) > Invalidate and Restart.
[image: Invalidate Caches]

If it's still not working maybe you should ask/report in youtrack.